# Doesn't the identity relation have to be a homogeneous relation?

Tags: relations, inverse

On the wikipedia page for converse relation it states:

> If $I$ represents the identity relation, then a relation $R$ may have an inverse as follows:
>
> A relation $R$ is called right-invertible if there exists a relation $X$ with ${\displaystyle R\circ X=I}$, and left-invertible if there exists a $Y$ with ${\displaystyle Y\circ R=I}$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are called the right and left inverse of $R$, respectively. Right- and left-invertible relations are called invertible. For invertible homogeneous relations all right and left inverses coincide; the notion inverse $R^{–1}$ is used. Then $R^{–1}$ = $R^T$ holds.

My question is that doesn't the identity relation only make sense if it is a homogenous relation i.e: $R\subset S\times S$? If so then the above would suggest that all left and right inverses are equivalent, which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true.

But there is *always* such set $S$. Simply take $S=\operatorname{dom}(R)\cup\operatorname{rng}(R)$, this is sometimes referred to as *the field of $R$* or $\operatorname{fld}(R)$.

If you have several relations, then you can simply take the union of their fields as your "set of interest".

Comment: So then what's the point in left invertible relations vs. right invertible relations?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: "For invertible homogeneous relations, all right and left inverses coincide" and if we have to take the field of the relation to make sense of the identity relation, then the relation is homogeneous no? And if it is homogeneous then both the left and right inverses coincide if they exist.

Comment: Then they might talk about the identity relation on the domain and range of $R$. Flag this as unclear, I don't know what to tell you about the original intention of whoever wrote that paragraph on Wikipedia. But I can tell you that while in general Wikipedia tends to be a good source for mathematical definitions, it's usually much better to learn from books.